# Pass QuerySet object in template. Django

Tags: python, django-templates

How can i pass QuerySet object in to template. And then Iterate through it in tempalte. If ican do it....?

Example

```
queryset =MyModel.objects.all()

return render_to_response('template.html',{'queryset':queryset})
```

How it'll looks in template?

Can I show field of foreigne key object in this template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{% for each_model in model %}
    #Do Something with model
    {{each_model.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Pol - Sure.  `{{ each_model.someForeignKey.someField }}`

Comment: How would I pass each_model to another template that has been included?

Something like 

{% for each_model in model %}
    {{render each_model as "model_card.html"}}
{% endfor %}